# Human matrix convert into zombie

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I face this questing in an interview. Please let me know possible answer for this questing.

We have a matrix like 3 X 3, 5 X 5 or 7 X 7. In mid we do have X(represent zombie) and 0(void or blank) or 1(Human) at all nodes. X created all adjacent human nodes zombie in a minute. 
  So how much time it will take to create all matrix zombie.

Comment: i don't understand your question can you improve it?

Comment: X is in middle in matrix. and it makes all adjacent nodes zombie in a min. calculate the time when all nodes will be zombile.

Comment: IOW that's a BFS...

Comment: As I understand for the word - **adjacent human nodes**  means only four other nodes in matrix - `node(x ,y-1 ) , node(x, y+1 ) , node(x-1,y) and node(x+1, y)` for any given node `node(x,y)`, is it the case? Also, I guess if adjacent nodes to a zombie node are only `0 ( void or blank ) `  and no humans there at adjacent nodes, matrix can't be converted to zombie , is that true?

Comment: I've made an edit that makes this question understandable. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the terminology fool you: this is a graph problem. I assume that a zombie can also reach the humans that are *diagonally adjacent* to it.

If you conduct a *Breadth first search* from the "Zombie point", you will be able to determine that time (if it exists). This is basically how you proceed: (code sample in Python)

```python
matrix = [['1', '0', '0'],['1', 'X', '1'],['0', '0', '0']]
mid = len(matrix)//2
yet_to_explore = [(mid,mid,0)]
explored_set = {} # This is a hashset of explored nodes
while [] != yet_to_explore:
    cur_vertex = yet_to_explore.pop(0)
    x = cur_vertex[0]
    y = cur_vertex[1]
    if (x,y) in explored_set:
        continue
    explored_set[(x,y)] = cur_vertex[2]
    matrix[x][y] = 'X'
    for i in range(-1,2):
        if 0 > x + i or len(matrix) <= x + i:
            continue
        for j in range(-1,2):
            if 0 > y + j or len(matrix) <= y + j:
                continue
            elif 0 == i and 0 == j:
                continue
            elif matrix[x+i][y+j]=='1':
                yet_to_explore.append((x+i, y+j, cur_vertex[2]+1))
# If your matrix contains a '1' after the BFS this means some human were not reachable (they are isolated) -> the desired time does not exist since not every human can be a zombie
# Else the time you are looking for is the following result:
time = max(list(explored_set.values()))
```

An example where there is a survivor:

```python
matrix = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
          ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'], # The human on the left will be contamined within 4 min
          ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
          ['1', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0'], # The human on the left will survive
          ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
          ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
          ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']] # The human on the right will be contamined within 3 min
```

The search for hypothetical survivors is left as an exercise.

Comment: I thought the question was: "how much time  it will take to create all matrix zombie"?

Comment: @KevinWallis Yeah, bad english is a curse to get understood. My understanding was this: "given a matrix with a zombie in the center and some humans, how much time will it take to get all the humans converted (if possible)?"